# knockout in mvc - simple example not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I got knockout to work before in MVC, but unfortunately I lost the code, and need help figuring it out.

I am trying to simply put an html page in the ~/wwwsource/ folder of my MVC project, and in that page I would like to demo a simple knockout example.

(Eventually, I actually want to use knockout inside MVC Views, using knockout right alongside Razor **if possible** but first I just would at least like to get a simple working example going, and extend from there.

I tried the following, which worked in JSFiddle but not in Visual Studio:

```
        <script src="lib/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js" type="text/javascript">

    // Here's my data model
    var ViewModel = function (first, last) {
        this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
        this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

        this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        }, this);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); 
</script>



<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the javascript before the html has been fully rendered. So when ko.applyBindingsis called the html as only partially loaded.

Easiest solution is to wrap the javascript in a document loaded callback using jQuery (which should exist because you're using knockout).

You also have some invalid script tag syntax.  Need to close knockout script tag before starting a new one for the page.

```
<script src="lib/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function (first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
       return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); 
})
</script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```